# Obtener valores repetidos en un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este JSON:

```javascript
countVotes =  "{participants":{"573185499102":"6","13013020122":"2","573012014822":"2"}}
```

Quisiera saber cómo obtener cuántas veces se repite un valor: por ejemplo, en el JSON vemos que el valor `2` se repite en dos keys.

He intentado con muchos, pero aún así no lo logro.

```javascript
var counts = {};
Object.keys(countVotes.participants).forEach(key => {
counts[countVotes[key]] = (counts[key] || 1) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Te comento un par de cosas, nose si generas el JSON a mano o dinamicamente, pero esta mal generado, las comillas te van a dar problemas. Por otro lado, comentas que el valor `2` se repite en dos keys, no son keys son values... los keys son los que estan a la izquierda de los dos puntos (`:`)... Por lo tanto entiendo que quieres saber cuantas veces se repiten los values repetidos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se crea una variable vacía para acumular cantidad de valores
repetidos, no se utiliza en este ejemplo el método **Object.keys()** si no
**Object.values()** utilizando el metodo **reduce** podemos obtener los valores repetodos de un **JSON**

```js
   const countVotes = {
        participants: {
          "573185499102": "6",
          "13013020122": "2",
          "573012014822": "2",
        },
   };
   
  const repetidos = Object.values(countVotes.participants).reduce(
    (acc, next) => ({
      ...acc,
      [next]: (acc[next] || 0) + 1
    }),
    {}
  );
  console.log(repetidos);
```